# React Navigation Nested Deeplinks Structure

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

Our app has a few tabs:

- Home
- Wallet & Interaction
- Profile

In the Wallet & Interaction tab the `MeInteractionsAndWalletStackScreen` is shown. This stack has a `MeInteractionsAndWallet` screen with a button in the top right which directs to the `CHatsScreen`. From the `ChatsScreen` a user can click on the chat to open the `ChatScreen` to continue the chat. So `MeInteractionsAndWallet` -> `ChatsScreen` -> `ChatScreen` is the structure.

The problem we have is:
We want the user to open the `MeInteractionsAndWallet` -> `ChatsScreen` -> `ChatScreen` screen when it opens the deeplink `/app/chat/:userId`. When we add a `MeInteractionsAndWalletStackScreen` to the linking and link the `ChatScreen` there and the user opens the deeplink then the app opens the `MeInteractionsAndWallet` and directly opens the `ChatScreen` on top of it, skipping the `ChatsScreen`. For now we just open the `ChatScreen` on the `HomeStackScreen` as a more user friendly fix.
But our goal is to open this structure (`MeInteractionsAndWallet` -> `ChatsScreen` -> `ChatScreen`) when the user opens a `/app/chat/:userId` deeplink.

How can we achieve this?

Below is part of the code.

Out `RootNavigator.tsx`

```
const linking: any = {
    prefixes: [
        'https://exploremomo.com',
    ],
    config: {
      screens: {
        Authenticated: {
            path: '/app',
            screens: {
                ProfileStackScreen: {
                    path: '/profile'
                },
                HomeStackScreen: {
                    screens: {
                        ChatScreen: {
                            path: '/chat/:userId'
                        },
                        UserAccount: {
                            path: '/user/:userId'
                        },
                        Organisation: {
                            path: '/organisation/:organisationId'
                        },
                        OrganisationEvent: {
                            path: '/organisation/:organisationId/event/:eventId'
                        },
                        OrganisationGroup: {
                            path: '/organisation/:organisationId/group/:groupId',
                        },
                        OrganisationGroupMessage: {
                            path: '/organisation/:organisationId/group/:groupId/message/:messageId',
                        }
                    }
                },
            }
        }
      }
    },
  };

return (<SafeAreaProvider>
            <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <NavigationContainer
                    linking={linking}
                >
                    {authData.data?.data?.user && meCurrentUser?.data ? <AuthenticatedStack /> : <AuthStack />}
                </NavigationContainer>
            </GestureHandlerRootView>
        </SafeAreaProvider>)
```

Our `AuthenticatedStack.tsx`

```
<View flex>
      <OnboardingAuthenticatedStack.Navigator 
        initialRouteName={shouldOnboard ? 'Onboarding' : 'Authenticated'}
      >
        <OnboardingAuthenticatedStack.Screen
          name="Onboarding"
          component={OnBoardingScreen}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
          }}
        />
        <OnboardingAuthenticatedStack.Screen
          name="Authenticated"
          component={AuthenticatedComponent}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
          }}
        />
      </OnboardingAuthenticatedStack.Navigator>
      <LocationPermissionSheet />
    </View>
```

Our `AuthenticatedComponent` in `AuthenticatedStack.tsx`

```
<View flex>
      
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          headerShown: false,
          showLabel: false,
          tabBarShowLabel: false
        })}
      >
        <Tab.Screen name="HomeStackScreen" component={HomeStackScreen} options={{
          title: 'Map'
        }} />
 
        <Tab.Screen name="MeInteractionsAndWalletStackScreen" component={MeInteractionsAndWalletStackScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="ProfileStackScreen" component={ProfileStackScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </View>
```

Our stacks in `AuthenticatedStack.tsx`

```
const OnboardingAuthenticatedStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const HomeStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const MyOrganizationsStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const UserInteractionsStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const MeWalletStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const MeInteractionsAndWalletStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const ChatsStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const ProfileStack = createNativeStackNavigator();


const HomeStackScreen = () => {
  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator>
      <HomeStack.Screen name='Map' options={{ title: 'Momo' }} component={HomeScreen} />
      <HomeStack.Screen name='OrganizationLocation' options={{ title: 'Location' }} component={OrganizationLocationScreen} />
      <HomeStack.Screen name='OrganizationLocationCheckedInUsers' options={{ title: 'Checked-In Users' }} component={OrganizationLocationCheckedInUsersScreen} />
      <HomeStack.Screen name='UserAccount' options={({ route }: any) => ({ title: route.params.userName })} component={UserAccountScreen} />
      <HomeStack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: 'modal' }}>
        <HomeStack.Screen name="ImageViewer" options={({ route }: any) => ({ title: route?.params ? route.params.title : 'ImageViewer' })} component={ImageViewerScreen}  />
      </HomeStack.Group>
      <HomeStack.Screen name="ChatScreen" options={{ title: 'Chat' }} component={ChatScreen} />
      <HomeStack.Screen name="Organisation" options={({ route }: any) => ({ title: route?.params ? route.params.title : 'Organisation' })} component={OrganisationScreen}  />
      <HomeStack.Screen name="OrganisationGroup" options={({ route }: any) => ({ title: route?.params ? route.params.title : 'Group' })} component={OrganisationGroupScreen}  />
      <HomeStack.Screen name="OrganisationGroupMessage" options={({ route }: any) => ({ title: 'Message' })} component={OrganisationGroupMessageScreen}  />
      <HomeStack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: 'modal' }}>
        <HomeStack.Screen name="CreateMessage" options={({ route }: any) => ({ title: route?.params?.title ? route.params.title : 'Write a Post' })} component={CreateMessageScreen}  />
      </HomeStack.Group>
      <HomeStack.Screen name="OrganisationEvent" options={({ route }: any) => ({ title: route?.params ? route.params.title : 'Event' })} component={OrganisationEventScreen}  />
      <HomeStack.Screen name='MyOrganizationAdminScreen' options={{ title: 'My Organisations' }} component={MyOrganizationAdminScreen} />
      <HomeStack.Screen name='MyOrganizationCreateEdit' options={{ title: 'Organisation' }} component={OrganizationCreateEditScreen} />
      <HomeStack.Screen name='MyOrganizationCreateEditSuperAdminActions' options={{ title: 'Super Admin Actions' }} component={OrganisationSuperAdminActionsScreen} />
      <HomeStack.Screen name='MyOrganizationCreateEditInvites' options={{ title: 'Invites' }} component={OrganisationAdminInvitesScreen} />
      <HomeStack.Screen name='MyOrganizationCreateEditGroups' options={{ title: 'Groups' }} component={OrganisationAdminGroupsScreen} />
      <HomeStack.Screen name='MyOrganizationEditMembers' options={{ title: 'Members' }} component={OrganisationAdminMembersScreen} />
      <HomeStack.Screen name='MyOrganizationCreateEditEvents' options={{ title: 'Events' }} component={OrganisationAdminEventsScreen} />
      <HomeStack.Screen name="MyOrganizationCreateEditLocations" options={{ title: 'Organisation Locations' }} component={OrganizationCreateEditLocationsScreen} />
      <HomeStack.Screen name='MyOrganizationLocationCreateEdit' options={{ title: 'Location' }} component={OrganizationLocationCreateEditScreen} />
      <HomeStack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: 'modal' }}>
        <HomeStack.Screen name='CreateEditGroup' options={({ route }: any) => ({ title: route?.params ? route.params.title : 'Create Group' })} component={GroupCreateEditScreen} />
      </HomeStack.Group>
      <HomeStack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: 'modal' }}>
        <HomeStack.Screen name='CreateEditEvent' options={({ route }: any) => ({ title: route?.params ? route.params.title : 'Create Event' })} component={EventCreateEditScreen} />
      </HomeStack.Group>
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  )
}



const MeInteractionsAndWalletStackScreen = () => {
  const navigation = React.useContext(NavigationContext);

  return (
    <MeInteractionsAndWalletStack.Navigator>
      <MeInteractionsAndWalletStack.Screen name='MeInteractionsAndWallet' 
        options={{ 
          title: 'Interactions & Wallet',
          headerRight: () => (
            remoteConfigToggleAllowMessages ? <Pressable onPress={() => navigation?.navigate('ChatsScreen')}>
              <Ionicons name="chatbubbles-outline" size={26} />
            </Pressable> : null
          ),
        }} 
        component={MeInteractionsAndWalletScreen} 
      />
      <MeInteractionsAndWalletStack.Screen name='UserAccount' options={({ route }: any) => ({ title: route.params.userName })} component={UserAccountScreen} />
      <MeInteractionsAndWalletStack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: 'modal' }}>
        <MeInteractionsAndWalletStack.Screen name="ImageViewer" options={({ route }: any) => ({ title: route?.params ? route.params.title : 'ImageViewer' })} component={ImageViewerScreen}  />
      </MeInteractionsAndWalletStack.Group>
      <MeInteractionsAndWalletStack.Screen name="ChatScreen" options={{ title: 'Chat' }} component={ChatScreen} />
      <MeInteractionsAndWalletStack.Screen name='ChatsScreen' options={{ title: 'Chats' }} component={ChatsScreen} />
    </MeInteractionsAndWalletStack.Navigator>
  )
}
```